# Why view is not creating?

Tags: oracle

```
create or replace view V_SBI_CLM_LOSSCAUSE 
AS select loss_cause_code, distinct loss_cause_name, 
   product_line_code, loss_cause_desc, event_id 
   from t_clm_losscause;
```

When i'm trying to run i'm getting

> Missing expresion

Any one pls help.. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the `DISTINCT` keyword before `SELECT`. `DISTINCT` keyword should apply to all selected columns.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_sbi_clm_losscause 
     AS SELECT DISTINCT
               loss_cause_code, 
               loss_cause_name, 
               product_line_code, 
               loss_cause_desc, event_id 
        FROM   t_clm_losscause;
```

Comment: I have some duplicates in loss_cause_name, i have to remove it with out affecting any other coloumns..

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 create or replace view V_SBI_CLM_LOSSCAUSE 
 AS select distinct loss_cause_name, 
 product_line_code, loss_cause_desc, event_id 
 from t_clm_losscause;
```

Comment: Sorry for the mistake.. as i removed FROM my query also i'm getting same error